# Calling AlertDialog from MPAndrioid RadarChart

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, mpandroidchart

I am able to make the RadarChart work with some static data. Now i want to display a alert dialog when users click on the radarchart to ask the user to input some data and then use this input data to redraw the chart.

I have created a MyMarkerView class which extends MarkerView and in the refreshContent method add the code for the Alert Dialog view.

But the problem is that whenever uses click the AlerDialog, the refreshContent is again called and a new alert Dialog is created - and the user is not able to enter anything.
Below is the code in the refreshContent method

```
       LayoutInflater li = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            View promptsView = li.inflate(R.layout.month_target_analysis_dialog, null);

            AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

            // set prompts.xml to alertdialog builder
            alertDialogBuilder.setView(promptsView);

            final EditText userInput1 = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.textView1Edit);
            final EditText userInput2 = (EditText) promptsView.findViewById(R.id.textView2Edit);

            // set dialog message
            alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
            alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            // get user input and set it to result
                            // edit text
                            //result.setText(userInput.getText());
                            String input1 = userInput1.getText().toString();
                            String input2 = userInput1.getText().toString();
                            if (userInput1.getError() == null && userInput2.getError() == null) {
                                //Do something
                            } else {
                            }
                        }
                    });
            alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",
                    new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    });

            // create alert dialog
            AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();

            // show it
            alertDialog.show();
        }
```

Below is the Xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/layout_root"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/l_target"
            android:textAppearance="@style/ItemMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textView1Edit"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            >
            <requestFocus />
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:text="@string/g_target"
            android:textAppearance="@style/ItemMedium" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/textView2Edit"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="50dp"
            android:clickable="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            >
        </EditText>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Any ideas how to disable the calling of refreshContent ?
Or is there any other better way of handling this ?

Thanks
Praveen

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to make it work using the MarkerView. Instead i defined a setOnChartGestureListener to catch all the possible action on the chart and then handled the necessary action when the action was caught.
Seems to be working.

```
 mChart.setOnChartGestureListener(new OnChartGestureListener() {
       @Override
            public void onChartSingleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "single tap");

            }
          @Override
            public void onChartDoubleTapped(MotionEvent me) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "double tap");
            }
}
```

Thanks